# Find Range of substring in NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, nsrange, nsmutableattributedstring

I have AttributedString with emoji like this " @Mervin tester "

Now I need to find a range of Mervin in this attributed String.

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " @Mervin tester ")

let range = // range for "Mervin" in above String.
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know `Mervin`? Or you are looking for `@SomeName`? Else, `let range = attributedString.string.rangeOfString("Marvin")` (in pseudo code, I'm not sure of the Swift methods names, but completion should help you).

Comment: @Larme Thank you, it's working. I was trying same with utf-8 string so it was showing the wrong result.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This extension should help you.

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    func rangeOf(string: String) -> Range<String.Index>? {
        return self.string.range(of: string)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
attributedString.rangeOf(string: "Mervin")
```

Comment: I am getting wrong rang and as well how to find the ranges when you have multiple Mervin in attributed string

Answer (score -1):

I wanted something similar but for `AttributedString` instead. It took me a while to find the solution, so I think I may document it here since this is the first search hit for my question.

```swift
let attributedString = AttributedString(" @Mervin tester ")
let substring = "Mervin"

// Iterating through all the occurrences of `substring`.
for range in attributedString.characters.ranges(of: substring) {
   // Do something with the current range
   attributedString[range].foregroundColor = .red
}
```